# wrapper script for Perl one-liner (for extracting columns from a text file)

Tags: perl, shell

I have this Perl one-liner for extracting columns from a text file, which I found in this forum.

```
perl -ane "print qq(@F[0,1,3,4]\n)" ./folder/input.txt 
    > ./short_files/output.txt
```

I need to run this on 352 input files having names `input1.txt, input2.txt,...,input352.txt` and produce 352 output files having names `output1.txt, output2.txt,..., output352.txt`.

Can anyone help me with a wrapper code so that I can run the Perl one-liner in a loop with input and output filenames changing every time?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a Perl solution:

```
for my $in_file (glob('input*.txt')) {
   ( my $out_file = $in_file ) =~ s/input/output/;

   open(my $fh_in, '<', $in_file)
      or die("Can't open \"$in_file\": $!\n");

   open(my $fh_out, '>', $out_file)
      or die("Can't create \"$out_file\": $!\n");

   while (<$fh_in>) {
      my @F = split;
      print $fh_out "@F[0,1,3,4]\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you in Unix? Do you have `bash`?

```
for i in {1..352} ; do
    perl -ale ... ./folder/input$i.txt > ./short_files/output$i.txt
done
```

Comment: I am in ubuntu. I tried running your code, but it gives me error Missing $ on loop variable at wrapper.pl line 2. I wrote your code in a file wrapper.pl and then ran it using perl wrapper.pl

Comment: You asked how to expand a *shell* command, so that's what he did. He even said for which *shell* it was: `bash`.